# Why didn't I see my Electorate badge?

Tags: support, electorate-badge

[Stack Overflow Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6494677/kondal?tab=profile)

Today I picked the Electorate badge, but it is still not visible on my account. Why is it too late arrive? When will it show on my profile? I voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Badges are not handed out in real time - there's a periodic task that checks for eligibility, and the badges are handed out then. I'd suggest waiting at *least* 24 hours after you *think* you should get a badge before wondering why you didn't get it.